# How can I update Python version when working on JGRASP on mac os?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, jgrasp

When I installed the new version of python 3.6.5, JGRASP was using the previous version, how can I use the new version on JGRASP?

Answer (score 0):

By default, jGRASP will use the first "python" on the system path.

The new version probably only exists as "python3". If that is the case, install jGRASP 2.0.5 Beta if you are using 2.0.4 or a 2.0.5 Alpha. Then, go to "Settings" > "Compiler Settings" > "Workspace", select language "Python" if not already selected, select environment "Python 3 (python 3) - generic", hit "Use" button, and "OK" the dialog.

Comment: I did as mentioned, however, when I tried to get the current version - By writing this: import sys
print(sys.version) , it showed the previous version. Does that mean it's using it?

Comment: Probably. Go through the steps again, and make sure you select "Python 3 (python 3) - generic" and not "Python 3 - generic". The first will call "python3" while the second will call "python". Both will assume Python 3 syntax in jGRASP.

Comment: Also, you can turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages", then look for "actual command sent" in the output to see what it is actually running.

Comment: Does "Python 3 (python 3) - generic" already exist? because I can't find it in the Environment options. Also, thank you for your help!